# Using 3d Touch to Segue to VC - how to populate optional values?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this handleShortCutItem method inside my AppDelegate to switch on the shortcut type the user taps in 3D touch to direct to the correct VC.  The problem I'm having is the VC has 2 optional values that I need to pass in otherwise obviously it breaks.

Normally this is done via a prepareForSegue method and assigning the values to the destination view controller.  i.e. dvc.optionalValue = x.

(1) How can I pass in the value here in the App Delegate? 
(2) the additional complexity is the VC I want to get to is embedded in a navigation controller so I need to say "present this UINavigationController and pass in these values to the VC embedded in it.

```
func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
            var handled = false

            guard ShortCutIdentifier(fullType: shortcutItem.type) != nil else {return false}
            guard let shortcutType = shortcutItem.type as String? else {return false}

switch (shortcutType) {
case ShortCutIdentifier.Second.type:
                handled = true


                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavClothingTableViewController") as! UINavigationController
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


                break

            default:
                break
            }

            return handled
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All that I needed to do was instantiate the embedded VC by calling .topViewController (to access the Navigation Controller's embedded VC), then I was able to pass values into the underlying VC:

```
     let clothingTVC = navVC.topViewController as! ClothingTableViewController
clothingTVC.store = Store(name: "test", clothingSizes: ["":""])
                clothingTVC.nameForShare = "Gary"
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```